# How to extract value from Exchange object in camel esb

Tags: apache-camel, fuseesb, jbossfuse

I have created a simple cxf web service. following is the body of soap message

```
 <soapenv:Body>
      <bean:getRTOEmployeeSalary>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <bean:arg0>sdf</bean:arg0>
      </bean:getRTOEmployeeSalary>
   </soapenv:Body>
```

My requirement is to extract the value of arg0 in my camel context file. i.e. i want to log the value of arg0. Please help me on this

```
    <route routePolicyRef="loggingInInterceptor">
        <from uri="cxf:bean:rtoemplyeeService"/>
        <setHeader headerName="exchange">
            <spel>${exchange}</spel>
        </setHeader>
        <log message="value of arg0======== "/>
        <convertBodyTo type="java.lang.String" id="stringInput"/>
        <bean ref="rtoEmpBean" method="getRTOEmployeeSalary" beanType="rtoEmpBean" id="govtRTOEmp"/>
    </route>
```

I need to use the value of arg0 here.

Answer (score 0):

We can use camel provided spring expression language to extract the value from exchange object. Since exchange object also resides in spring container.
below will be code src to extract the value of arg0 in camel context-

```
<setHeader headerName="arg0">
        <spel>#{exchange.in.body.get(0)}</spel>
</setHeader>
```

This will set the value of arg0 of soap message in a header named arg0.
http://camel.apache.org/spel.html